# Android TextView intricate alignment

Tags: android, textview, alignment

community.

The desired effect is to have `TextView` that:

1. has left-aligned text
2. is glued to the right to its right-aligned sibling control
3. adjusts to the available horizontal space e.g. wraps its text if needed

1/ More than the optimal `TextView` + `ImageView` width:

```
|---Empty-space---|---TextView---|--Image--|
|                 |1. Aa         |         |
|                 |2. Bbb cccc   |  [---]  |
|                 |3. Ddd eeee ff|         |
|-----------------|--------------|---------|
|                 |              |         |
.                 .              .         .
.                 .              .         .
.                 .              .         .
```

2/ Less than optimal `TextView` + `ImageView` width:

- the `TextView` wraps its text
- no empty space to the left of the `TextView` due to low available horizontal space

```
||-TextView-|--Image--|
||1. Aa     |         |
||2. Bbb    |         |
||cccc      |  [---]  |
||3. Ddd    |         |
||eeee ff   |         |
||----------|---------|
||          |         |
..          .         .
..          .         .
..          .         .
```

Asking the question after trying numerous things with linear and constraint layouts.
Satisfying conditions #1 and #2 from above is easily achieved by setting the width of the `TextView` to `wrap_content`, its `textAlignment="textStart"` (by default) and the `gravity` (not `layout_gravity`) for the whole `LinearLayout` to `end`. The right alignment for both controls - `TextView` and `ImageView`, when using a `ConstraintLayout`, is achieved by gluing the `ImageView` to the right and then setting the `constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"` for the `TextView`.

The problem comes when the last condition (#3) should be satisfied as well - make the `TextView`'s text wrappable. This is achievable by setting the `TextView`'s `width="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"` (in case of `LinearLayout`) or just setting `width="0dp"` for the `ConstraintLayout` scenario.

Any suggestions are appreciated and welcome.